# Reversible 4-switch buck-boost?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, converter, buck-boost

Can a 4-switch buck-boost be reversible?

[image]

The base scheme seems symmetrical but I did not find any reversible design.
Do you have an exemple of such a design?

Answer (score 4):

> Can a 4-switch buck-boost be reversible?

Yes, it is inherently bidirectional, but for it to work, the circuit in charge of driving the FETs must support it. If that's the case, it can control current or voltage on one side, or the other.

Many such cases, here's an [example from TI](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidt046/tidt046.pdf?ts=1614895843853).

Comment: Thank you.
And it makes me realize that I have to search with the "bi-directionnal" keyword and not "reversible".

Comment: Yes, that's the keyword ;)